# Is it normal that a node in a weighted directed graph gets a higher measure of betwenness centrality when its edge weights are lower?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a weighted directed graph and I use `cytoscape.js` library to measure betweenness centrality of the nodes. However, I noticed that the nodes that have lower edge weight actually tend to have higher betweenness centrality even if they are positioned the same way in the network as the other nodes with the higher edge weight.

Shouldn't it be the other way round?

Comment: I don't know the details of the definitions but my intuition is the opposite of yours. If a node is connected by edges of low weight then the lengths of paths from that node to elsewhere will tend to be shorter, so the node will be more central.

Comment: @EthanBolker I always thought of weight as the strength of the connection between the nodes, not its length. Like a throughput capacity. In which case my intuition should be correct...

Comment: Either intuitive  interpretation of "weight" can be right. One is the inverse of the other. Which is appropriate depends on context. Look at the definition of betweenness to decide in this case. (Note: I have not thought this through and don't know the definition. I'm just trying to help with the words.)